# Nearest value in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am supposed write a function that is passed two parameters: a one-dimensional array of int values, and an integer value. The function finds the value in the array that is closest in value to the second parameter.  My code works but not when I enter numbers 1-5 my output is 0.  When I enter numbers above 5 then I start getting accurate results.  I am not too sure why this is happening but here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 5;

int searchNearest(int anArray[],int key)
{
int value = abs(key - anArray[0]);
int num = 0;

for(int x = 0;x < MAX; x++)
{
    if(value > abs(key - anArray[x]))
    {
        value = abs(key - anArray[x]);
        num = anArray[x];
    }
}

return num;

}

int main()
{
int A[MAX] = {3,7,12,8,10};

int search;

int nearest;

cout << "Enter a number to search: ";

cin >> search;

nearest = searchNearest(A,search);

cout << "The nearest number is: " << nearest << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your original code, numbers 1-5 are closest to the first element of the array.  Because of this, the code in the `if` statement is never executed, and when you return `num`, you return its initial value, which happens to be `0`.  To fix this, just initialize `num` differently:

```
int num = anArray[0];  // <-- used to be 0
```

Comment: Ahh I knew I was overlooking something.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nick This is something that's pretty easy to diagnose with a debugger (or using `printf` or `cout` statements).  It's also far less frustrating than staring at the code.